# PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet dynamic style

Tags: php, colors, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I using

```
PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet
```

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
/* @var $sheet \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\Worksheet */
```

And prepare array with all data in another function. Then I put array to PhpSpreadSheet

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->fromArray($content);
```

The array is new every time. I don't know beforehand how many rows there will be. I need to paint some of them. How do I pass the cells to paint directly through the array?

I tried to paint some first rows, but I can't get  number of next row to paint.

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

Comment: Can't you do `count($content)` to get the number of rows?

Comment: Yes I can. There are intermediate totals, and I want to highlight them in color. For example, a total of 150 lines. now I want to highlight 24, 40, 133 lines. and on the next report other line numbers.

Comment: You could iterate through `$content` to search for specific strings, then extract the index while inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for this advice! I will do it.